# Excel CHOOSE Value Error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using `MATCH` and `CHOOSE` to populate a table. Basically, I want `CHOOSE` to return values to an "11 row and 5 column" table from 52 different tables. Formula is below.

```
=+CHOOSE(MATCH($B$3,List!$M$5:$M$14),SAMS!$C$4:$G$14,SAMS!$C$17:$G$27,SAMS!$C$30:G$40,SAMS!C$43:G$53,SAMS!$C$56:$G$66,SAMS!$C$69:$G$79,SAMS!$C$82:$G$92,SAMS!$C$95:$G$105,SAMS!$C$108:$G$118,SAMS!$C$121:$G$131).
```

When `MATCH` returns `1`, `CHOOSE` works. But when it returns any other number, `CHOOSE` does not work. Can you help? Thanks Ben

Comment: I hope the pending edit is to turn the formula into code{}

Comment: (1) Do you realize that you are missing three `$` signs?   (2) You say that you want to “return values … from 52 different tables”.   How is that supposed to happen when you have only 10 choices?   If your actual formula lists 52 choices, (2a) thank you for editing it down to 10, but (2b) you should have *said* that you were presenting incomplete information, and (2c) it would have been nice if you had reduced it even more — say, enough that the formula could fit on one line.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) Are you *sure* that `MATCH` is returning a valid value?  (3a) Have you used “Evaluate Formula”?  (3b) Have you tried replacing the `MATCH` call with a simple cell reference?  (These are basic debugging procedures.)  (3c) What debugging have you done?  (4) Please don’t post a question saying that something “does not work”.  What does it do?  … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You're using choose to select a range as a result.  Choose selects a single value.  But even if it could, how can you fit a range in a single result cell?  What you're doing in the formula isn't valid.  I'm curious what you get when match returns 1.

Comment: @fixer1234:  I got the OP's formula to work (replacing the ```MATCH``` call with a simple cell reference) by applying it to a 5×11 rectangular range and making it an array formula.

Comment: @Scott, my brain has shut down for the night and I'm not following what you changed that would allow it to work.  In the end, CHOOSE has to select a single result value in the OP's formula.  I could see it returning a string representing a range if the CHOOSE result was part of something like an INDIRECT expression, or maybe an array formula that carried the whole thing to it's result.  But the OP's formula results in a range being stored in a cell.  (cont'd)

Comment: If that works, I'll throw away all of my archive/compression utilities, because you could hold near infinite content in a cell.  If you bundle that as a bonus with the bookmark utility you mentioned the other day, you'll be one rich guy!  :-)  So I must be missing something.  I'll have to pick this up again when I return.

Comment: @scott: could you share the formula that you used as am not clear with "replacing the MATCH call with a simple cell reference".

Comment: Thanks guys for taking the time to look at my problem given the fact the question was laden with errors. I posted in a hurry as  I was rushing from the office and we had terrible weather.

Comment: @scott: Yes, when value for MATCH is 1 it  populates the table. So CHOOSE will work for a table if the formula is one in a way that It should.  View Add Edit Delete Extra
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
Y 0 0 0 0
Y 0 0 0 0

Comment: @scott: View Add Edit Delete Extra
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!
#VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE! #VALUE!

Comment: =+CHOOSE(MATCH($B$3,List!$M$5:$M$14),SAMS!$C$4:$G$14,SAMS!$C$17:$G$27,SAMS!$C$30:G$40,SAMS!C$43:G$53,SAMS!$C$56:$G$66,SAMS!$C$69:$G$79,SAMS!$C$82:$G$92,SAMS!$C$95:$G$105,SAMS!$C$108:$G$118,SAMS!$C$121:$G$131)    I used a named range LIST in my MATCH formula

Comment: With F9 when MATCH is 2 this is the result 
 {"Y","Y","Y","Y",0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0}

Comment: when MATCH is =1 this is the result {0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0;"Y",0,0,0,0}

Comment: Hey guys, i found a solution. The key was @fixer1234 saying CHOOSE can only choose a cell. So I referenced it 1by1. Painful but it worked. I had to create a big CHOOSE and several other CHOOSEs as there was an indirect with data validation. Crazy I know.Thanks for your efforts

Comment: @BernardOche,kudos.  Consider posting your solution as an answer.

Comment: BTW, it isn't that CHOOSE can only choose a cell, it returns a single selection from a list based on the index value.  If that is the entire formula (CHOOSE result = cell result), it needs to be something that can be contained in a cell.  The problem was trying to contain a range (multiple cells) in a single cell.

Comment: =+IFERROR(CHOOSE(MATCH($A$3,List!$J$4:$J$11),CHOOSE(MATCH($B$3,List!$M$5:$M$14),SAMS!C4,SAMS!C17,SAMS!C30,SAMS!C43,SAMS!C56,SAMS!C69,SAMS!C82,SAMS!C95,SAMS!C108,SAMS!C121),CHOOSE(MATCH($B$3,List!$N$5:$N$10),SAMS!C134,SAMS!C147,SAMS!C160,SAMS!C173,SAMS!C186,SAMS!C199),CHOOSE(MATCH($B$3,List!$O$5:$O$12),SAMS!C212,SAMS!C225,SAMS!C238,SAMS!C251,SAMS!C264,SAMS!C277,SAMS!C290,SAMS!C303)),"dropdown")  its longer than that just to give an idea

Comment: @fixer1234 now it makes sense that while i was trying to fit a range in a range, what I was doing was fit a range in a cell.  Clearly I need to work on my excel